# Rails inserting multiple records for single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, insert, records

How shall I set the form fields to be able to insert multiple rows in the database for a single model.

I am updating a div with another link and cannot use the form helper. So I need to set the field names manually.

I have a post model and it has a title field. 
  I want to insert i posts to db like post[0][title] But when I name the form field like this It gets 0 as string and does not record.

Also I tried to set the Array my self from Rails Console like

```
post = Array.new
post << [:title => "title 1"]
post << [:title => "title 2"]
sav = Post.new(post)
sav.save
```

And still nothing is saved.

Answer (score 7):

```
posts = Array.new
posts << {:title => "title 1"}
posts << {:title => "title 2"}
Post.create(posts)
```

Comment: Just remember this method doesn't actually do a mass insert into the database, it still inserts each record one-by-one.

Answer (score 6):

is this what you're trying to do?

```
posts = []
posts << Post.new(:title => "title 1")
posts << Post.new(:title => "title 2")

posts.each do |post|
  post.save
end
```