# I need help to insert multiple records in rails3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hai friends i need one help........

I have two tables students and attendences.
In students table i have stdname classname stdID fields
In attendence table i have attdID stdID AttdDate fields.

Now i have view like this:

class: ***_*___** section: **__*_*** Search(button)
(Then i got list of perticular class and section students)
StudentName

Raju
RAvi
Rekha

Like this all students now i want to insert the attdstatus to each student like this:

StudentName            AttdStaus    AttdDate
Raju                   ***_***     ***_*_**
Ravi                   ***_***      ***_*_**

Submit(button)

{Then the total students attendence have to insert into the attendence table.}
Please anybody help me by giving hints to  do this? My Email ID is chand5055@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the [activerecord-import gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki)

There are examples on the other end of that link. You might have to look at deeper examples in the unit tests but I would expect it to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to understand, but I'll give it a shot:  For starters, I'd say be more explicit about naming your table columns.  For a bit, I was wondering why you'd have standard_id (stdID) in your students table.

Next, I'd think a little more about your model structures.  Think of your students as they are in the real world.  They're unique people, so think of them as unique objects.  The same as your courses (not classes, since that's a reserved word in OO programming.):  A course has a name, a teacher, a start time, and end time, a subject etc.  The same goes for your attendances table.  It's got a student, and a course, and a date.

The associations would be something like:

```
Student
has_many :attendances
has_many :courses, :through => :enrollments

Attendance
belongs_to :student
belongs_to :course

Course
has_many :students, :through => :enrollments
has_many :attendances

Enrollment
belongs_to :students
belongs_to :courses
```

Beyond this, I don't think there's enough information to help out more specifically.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Hai Pope Poopinpants......... Thanks for your reply.... Yeah I mentioned name conversions as my own Ok I understood and one more help I need how to insert multiple records at a time in rails3.0? Can u please give any example application?

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495705/rails-inserting-multiple-records-for-single-model