# Best way to import 4000 rows from csv file to sqlite database in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, csv, import

So I have a csv file with approximately 4000 rows that I need read from a Rails app.  I plan to have this import performed once or twice a week.

Using csv-mapper, I am able to perform this operation (Delete current table, repopulate/save) however it takes a long time.

What is the best way to bulk import a csv file in a situation like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating multiple records at one time.  Here is a similar question [Rails inserting multiple records for single model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495705/rails-inserting-multiple-records-for-single-model)

I suggest you don't try to do all 4000 rows at once, but maybe break it down into smaller chunks of 10-20